# How to typehint FastAPI depends()

Tags: dependency-injection, fastapi, type-hinting, mypy

For example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


def thing(x: int) -> str:
    return f"x is : {x}"


@app.get("/")
async def root(x: int = Depends(thing)):
    return {"message": x.upper()}
```

Here the input might be an integer, but the `Depends(thing)` is going to convert it to a string instead.

When running mypy on this code the following error is returned :

```
error: "int" has no attribute "upper"  [attr-defined]
```

It seems as though the type-hints necessary are present, but I'm not sure how to use them in this case.

I wondered if there was something 'clever' that could be done with `thing.__annotations__['return']`, but I'm not really clever enough to know what.

Comment: Any reason for not typehinting it as what the dependency returns, i.e. `x: str = Depends(thing))`?

Comment: @MatsLindh I guess that makes more sense - I guess I feel as though I would lose some documentation as a result, but  really the documentation for `int` would be on the function which is a dependency.

Comment: Yes, the dependency should be resolved as expecting `int` as the input parameter; the signature in the view function itself is what the _function can expect the type of `x` to be in that function_. If you look at the `/docs` endpoint, you'll see how the input parameters has been documented. Dependencies will can have far more advanced dependencies (such as input models, multiple parameters, etc.) than a single int, and they will usually be documented correctly.